# Connect black dots on image with a line (Pore Network Connection)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, imagej

As part of my research, I have conducted an X-ray micro-CT scan of a rock sample. I have a 2D slice of the scan that I processed using the ImageJ software to find the pore space of the rock. The pore space is generally the portion of the rock that is composed of empty space where something can be stored.

On the slice the pore space is depicted in black while the rock matrix is white. The main task now is to connect the black spots together so if i go from left to right I will have a connected pore network. If i put a drop of water on left it should move to right via the connected pore space.

At this point we can ignore very small black spots and focus on the larger ones. Also I need to connect the spots so we can go left to right. other connections can also be made but the main idea is to have a left to right movement possible at the end of the task.

Would be happy have suggestions on how I can approach this.

Thank you!

PS - Image attached [[image: pore network[1]]

Once I get the pores connected I will transfer the design on a chip for an experiment like this [image]

Comment: How do YOU propose these dots should be joined (manually)? The image you've posted is as random as it gets and joining "from left to right" isn't good enough

Comment: Pretend you only had the input image, now attempt to recreate the same red connected spots as in your desired output image. I almost guarantee you will not be able to recreate the same exact image. My point is that there needs to be some algorithm or rule which defines how to each black spot is connected. If you provide us this we can help create a programmatic solution :) Currently, I have no idea how you generated the red lines. If there is no rule on how to connect the spots, the best you can do is a random connection using morphology closing

Comment: Thank you for your comment @nathancy. Actually I drew those red lines myself to  try to explain better what i was describing. What I mean is that when you look at it yourself, you can notice some pattern which i drew with the red lines manually. Since we have different rock samples it will be diffreent each time so I want to create a program to do that. To connect a line joining thorigh the intense black spot region. I hope I explained well

Comment: @RickM. I understand it will be difficult to do manually each time, that's why i was hoping to see if there can be a solution algorithmically or mathematically.  Something like this https://media.springernature.com/original/springer-static/image/art%3A10.1007%2Fs00542-019-04612-y/MediaObjects/542_2019_4612_Fig2_HTML.png